# How to track down the mistake in this merge function?

Tags: python-3.x, mergesort

I can't figure out what the problem with this merge sort implementation is. I've confirmed the problem is in the `merge` function rather than `merge_sort` by replacing `merge` with the same function from some examples found online and it works fine, however I can't find the mistake in my implementation.

- Expected result: list sorted in order from smallest to largest.
- Actual result: left side of list modified (not in order) and right side unmodified.

I've tried adding print statements at various points in the program and it looks like the problem is related to `rightList` not being created properly but I can't figure out why.

What can I do to track down the cause of this?

Code:

```
def merge_sort(toSort, left, right):
  # check if we have more than one remaining element
  if left >= right:
    return
  # get middle of array, note the result needs to be an int
  mid = (left + right) // 2
  # call merge sort on the left and right sides of the list
  merge_sort(toSort, left, mid)
  merge_sort(toSort, mid+1, right)
  # merge the results
  merge(toSort, left, right, mid)

# merge function taking a list along with the positions 
# of the start, middle and end
def merge(toSort, left, right, mid):
  # split the list into two separate lists based on the mid position
  leftList = toSort[left:mid+1]
  rightList = toSort[mid+1:right+1]

  # variables to track position in left and right lists and the sorted list
  lIndex = 0 
  rIndex = 0
  sIndex = lIndex

  # while there are remaining elements in both lists
  while lIndex < len(leftList) and rIndex < len(rightList):

    #if the left value is less than or equal to the right value add it to position sIndex in toSort
    # and move lIndex to next position
    if leftList[lIndex] <= rightList[rIndex]:
      toSort[sIndex] = leftList[lIndex]
      lIndex = lIndex + 1
    # otherwise set sIndex to right value and move rIndex to next position
    else:
      toSort[sIndex] = rightList[rIndex]
      rIndex = rIndex + 1
    sIndex = sIndex + 1
  # add the remaining elements from either leftList or rightList
  while lIndex < len(leftList):
    toSort[sIndex] = leftList[lIndex]
    lIndex = lIndex + 1
    sIndex = sIndex + 1

  while rIndex < len(rightList):
    toSort[sIndex] = rightList[rIndex]
    rIndex = rIndex + 1
    sIndex = sIndex + 1

unsorted = [33, 42, 9, 37, 8, 47, 5, 29, 49, 31, 4, 48, 16, 22, 26]   
print(unsorted)
merge_sort(unsorted, 0, len(unsorted) - 1)
print(unsorted)
```

Output:

```
[33, 42, 9, 37, 8, 47, 5, 29, 49, 31, 4, 48, 16, 22, 26]

[16, 22, 26, 49, 31, 4, 48, 29, 49, 31, 4, 48, 16, 22, 26]
```

### Edit

Link to example of code in colab: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1z5ouu_aD1QM0unthkW_ZGkDlrnPNElxm?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index variable into `toSort`, `sIndex` should be initialized to `left` instead of `0`.

Also note that it would be more readable and consistent to pass `right` as 1 + the index of the last element of the slice, which is consistent with the slice notation in python and would remove the `+1`/`-1` adjustments here and there. The convention where `right` is included is taught in java classes, but it is error prone and does not allow for empty slices.

Using simpler index variable names would help readability, especially with more indent space.

Here is a modified version:

```py
# sort the elements in toSort[left:right]
def merge_sort(toSort, left, right):
   # check if we have more than one remaining element
   if right - left < 2:
      return
   # get middle of array, note: the result needs to be an int
   mid = (left + right) // 2
   # call merge sort on the left and right sides of the list
   merge_sort(toSort, left, mid)
   merge_sort(toSort, mid, right)
   # merge the results
   merge(toSort, left, mid, right)

# merge function taking a list along with the positions 
# of the start, middle and end, in this order.
def merge(toSort, left, mid, right):
   # split the list into two separate lists based on the mid position
   leftList = toSort[left : mid]
   rightList = toSort[mid : right]

   # variables to track position in left and right lists and the sorted list
   i = 0
   j = 0
   k = left

   # while there are remaining elements in both lists
   while i < len(leftList) and j < len(rightList):

      # if the left value is less than or equal to the right value add it to position k in toSort
      # and move i to next position
      if leftList[i] <= rightList[j]:
         toSort[k] = leftList[i]
         i += 1
      # otherwise set it to right value and move j to next position
      else:
         toSort[k] = rightList[j]
         j += 1
      k += 1
   # add the remaining elements from either leftList or rightList
   while i < len(leftList):
      toSort[k] = leftList[i]
      i += 1
      k += 1

   while j < len(rightList):
      toSort[k] = rightList[j]
      j += 1
      k += 1

unsorted = [33, 42, 9, 37, 8, 47, 5, 29, 49, 31, 4, 48, 16, 22, 26]   
print(unsorted)
merge_sort(unsorted, 0, len(unsorted))
print(unsorted)
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved the issue and I appreciate the feedback on readability. I'm more familiar with java so I'll need to watch out for conventions live the one you mention where old habits are getting me in trouble.